# Ignore specific files in packrat search

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, packrat

I am creating reports using R, RStudio, `knitr`, and `packrat`. I have a project folder structure similar to below:

```
project_folder/
    - packrat/
    - .Rprofile
    - analaysis_folder/
        - library.R
        - child.rnw
    - data_folder/
    - knitr_rnw_location/
        - file.rnw
        - .Rprofile
```

And have set up the `.Rprofile` with the appropriate lines in the main `project_folder` and the subdirectory of the `.rnw` file, according to the recommendations given in [RStudio's Limitations and Caveats page](https://rstudio.github.io/packrat/limitations.html).

When I run `packrat::init()` at the `project_folder` level, the `packrat` folder is set up. Then when I open the `file.rnw` the `packrat` library is all set up.

However, when I execute `packrat::snapshot()` it gives errors

`Unable to tangle file knitr_rnw_location/file.rnw; cannot parse depndencies`

and fails. Is there a way to tell `packrat` to ignore my `.rnw` files? All `library()` are called from separate `.R` scripts and are `source()` through the `.rnw` files. It also searches any variables declared in the `knitr` chunks and gives the error

`Error in eval(x, envir = envir): object 'my_variable_name' not found`

In the end, it does state

```
Snapshot written to "~/project_folder/packrat/packrat.lock"
```

So I can only assume that `packrat::snapshot()` was successful. Has anyone else run into the same issue when working with `knitr` and `packrat`?

Much appreciated,